# how to import mssql database in Mysql

Tags: database

Now our client using a billing software, which is developed in Vb.net and using mssql for database.  Want to convert the project in codeigntier. How can i convert the current database into mysql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hehe, short story... don't. Install http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20098 to communicate to the mssql database. its simple pdo, so code igniter should be able to work with it

Comment: how can i work in online

Comment: You know, you put the dll files in the php/ext dir, put it in php.ini and start workin with it.

Comment: If any other option for do this..